# How to parse themed references from a resource array

Tags: android, android-resources

For our current app, almost all of our resources are themed.  For the most part this works, but I can't figure out how to parse themed resources out of a resource array.

The code we have for parsing color arrays looks something like this:

```
TypedArray ca = getResources().obtainTypedArray(id);
int[] colors = new int[ca.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++)
{
    colors[i] = ca.getColor(i, 0);
}
ca.recycle();
```

That works fine as long as the array looks something like this:

```
<array name="color_array_foo">
    <item>#123456</item>
    <item>#789ABC</item>
</array>
```

But if the array looks like this:

```
<array name="color_array_foo">
    <item>?attr/color_nothing</item>
    <item>?attr/color_1</item>
</array>
```

with the necessary stuff elsewhere in resources like:

```
<attr name="color_1" format="color"/>
...
<style name="Base" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="color_1">#123456</item>
    ...
</style>
```

then it throws this exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x2
   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:327)
```

I've looked around at the various methods of TypedArray, like peekValue() and getResourceId(), but I can't figure out anything that will let me dereference the themed attribute to the actual color value.  How do I do that?

---

Edit: This smells like it's closer, but still isn't right:

```
TypedArray ca = getResources().obtainTypedArray(id);
int [] c = new int[ca.length()];
for (int i=0; i<c.length; i++)
{
    if (ca.peekValue(i).type == TypedValue.TYPE_REFERENCE ||
        ca.peekValue(i).type == TypedValue.TYPE_ATTRIBUTE)
    {
        // FIXME: Probably need to split the above if, and for
        // TYPE_ATTRIBUTE, do some additional dereferencing?
        c[i] = ca.getResources().getColor(ca.peekValue(i).data);
    }
    else
    {
        c[i] = ca.getColor(i, 0);
    }
}
ca.recycle();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use method [public boolean resolveAttribute (int resid, TypedValue outValue, boolean resolveRefs)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.Theme.html#resolveAttribute(int,%20android.util.TypedValue,%20boolean))

```
TypedArray ca = getResources().obtainTypedArray(id);
int[] c = new int[ca.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    if (ca.peekValue(i).type == TypedValue.TYPE_ATTRIBUTE) {
        TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
        getTheme().resolveAttribute(ca.peekValue(i).data, typedValue, true);
        c[i] = typedValue.data;
    } else {
        c[i] = ca.getColor(i, 0);
    }
}
ca.recycle();
```

it works for

```
<resources>

    <attr name="color_2" format="color"/>
    <color name="color_2">#002</color>
    <color name="color_3">#003</color>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="color_2">@color/color_2</item>
    </style>

    <array name="color_array_foo">
        <item>#001</item>
        <item>?attr/color_2</item>
        <item>@color/color_3</item>
    </array>
</resources>
```

Comment: Minor correction: you need a Context to call getTheme() on.  Context is passed in to a View's constructors.  Other than that, it works, thanks!